# Emulator show empty white screen problem on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mono

I was testing what  I done with android emulator and it always worked well but yesterday it suddenly shows my app as a just white blank screen. I dont know the reason why.
This my MainActivity class

```
    using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HealthCareApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "HealthCareApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Forms.SetFlags("Brush_Experimental");
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new Xamarin.Forms.Application());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs ( now its giving a error : "initializecomponent is inaccessible due to its protection level" )

```
    using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace HealthCareApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `LoadApplication` you are supposed to load _your_ application.

Comment: @Cheesebaron so is it wrong?  Do you have any idea about solution?

Comment: @burakzbc Hi, do you mean it works before? If project is too old, you could update the version of nuget packages to the latest to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `App` class somewhere in your project, which contains information of which Forms page to show first and setup stuff like services in a IoC container etc.

Instead of calling

```
LoadApplication(new Xamarin.Forms.Application());
```

You should probably call:

```
LoadApplication(new App());
```

Comment: Now it sends a error "initializecomponent is inaccessible due to its protection level ". I added app.xaml.cs to question above. My deadline almost coming within hours so I am so sad. If I make you busy sorry for that :(

Comment: Is it a compilation error? Can you please post the full error message?

Comment: Yes, it is compilation error and full error is only this one "initializecomponent is inaccessible due to its protection level "